Facebook private reply API, An unknown error has occurred
During development, the private reply API (https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/messages) was working correctly. However, after my app's review was rejected, the API started failing.
The error I encounter is:

"An unknown error has occurred."

Is it possible for an API to stop functioning after an app review rejection?
Investigated Details:
The token's validity has been confirmed as fine via the developer tools.
The COMMENT-ID was obtained from the Webhook, so it should be correct.
The PAGE-ID works with other APIs, so it also appears to be correct.
